# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [String].getDescribe()

Tags: apex, controller, class, describesobject, describefieldresult

I've checked the other answers and googled a lot, can't seem to find the answer to why this doesn't work:

```
public List<SelectOption> AccountIndustryOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
public List<SelectOption> getAccountIndustryOptions(){
    if(AccountIndustryOptions == null){
        setAccountIndustryOptions();
    }
    return AccountIndustryOptions;
}

public void setAccountIndustryOptions(){
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult industry = Account.Industry.getDescribe();

    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> P = industry.getPicklistValues();
    
    AccountIndustryOptions.add(new SelectOption('All','All'));
    
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry i : P)
    {
        if(P[i].isActive())
        {
            AccountIndustryOptions.add(new SelectOption(P[i].getLabel(),P[i].getLabel()));
        }
    }
}
```

I get error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [String].getDescribe()" for line 2
I can't find what's wrong.

Comment: Do you have an object instance in the same class called `Account`?

Comment: @BarCotter No.. I dont :s I assumed it was being fetched from the standard object Account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of avoiding this problem of the `account` SObject variable hiding the `Account` SObjectType (as Apex is case insensitive) is to qualify the `Account` SObjectType reference like this:

```
DescribeFieldResult industry = Schema.Account.Industry.getDescribe();
```

This avoids having to change other existing code.

Comment: Amazing this actually compiles! I was trying something with schema before of what I found on this link https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000092mbIAA but I didnt understand that I should have replaced the sObject with Account.. Basic newbie errors. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 5):

Having a `SObject` instance called `account` will cause this error. See the example below:

```
Account account = [Select Id, Industry from Account limit:1];
Schema.DescribeFieldResult industry = Account.Industry.getDescribe();
```

The above code throws the error `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [String].getDescribe()` because `Account.Industry` now resolves to the `Industry` field on the `account` record, which is a string. Try rename your reference to `account` to something like `selectedAccount` or `currentAccount`

---

Another issue in your code is the `for loop`. `i` is the instance of your PicklistEntry so you don't need to use `P[i]`. Your code should look something like this (I've renamed the variables to make it clearer):

```
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues = industry.getPicklistValues();
accountIndustryOptions.add(new SelectOption('All','All'));
for (Schema.PicklistEntry picklistValue : picklistValues) {
    if (picklistValue.isActive()) {
        accountIndustryOptions.add(new SelectOption(picklistValue.getLabel(), picklistValue.getLabel()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, I'm trying to refactor some parts of this old salesforce app called Findnearby. Check row 503 here http://pastebin.com/D05HzR4T they have no other referance to the Account object (That I can see), so how did THAT code ever work?

Comment: Thanks for sorting out my for loop. I'm really terrible at apex coding since I'm mainly a front end developer and just have basic knowledge about C#..

Comment: "rename your reference to account to something like selectedAccount or currentAccount", by renaming the variable how would that change Industry from being a string?

Comment: If you cant find the reference then try changing the line to `Schema.Account.Industry.getDescribe();`, which will let SF know that you are referring to a field on the Account object

Answer (score -1):

Just Change the method

```
public void setAccountIndustryOptions(){
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult industry = Account.Industry.getDescribe();

    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> P = industry.getPicklistValues();

    AccountIndustryOptions.add(new SelectOption('All','All'));

    for(Schema.PicklistEntry i : P)
    {
        if(i.isActive())
        {
            AccountIndustryOptions.add(new SelectOption(i.getLabel(),i.getLabel()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue is that row 2 .getDescribe(); is giving me the error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [String].getDescribe()"